# Return Two Array with C++

Tags: c++, arrays

Hi guys I'm trying to make a function to cut a card game stored in a array in half, I just would like to know if I can return two different array with my function

```
string* couperJeu(int idJoueur, string tab[52]){
    string jeuJoueur1[26];
    string jeuJoueur2[26];

    if (idJoueur == 0){
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
            jeuJoueur1[i] = tab[i];
        }
    }
    if (idJoueur == 1){
        for (int y = 26; y < 52; y++) {
            jeuJoueur2[y] = tab[y];
        }
    }
    return(jeuJoueur1, jeuJoueur2);
}
```

Comment: A hint; no matter what your native language, always program in English.

Comment: Use some struct or class.

Comment: The arrays go out of scope. So no. Instead use a vector and return a pair of vectors

Comment: First of all, read about [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) (or [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)). Secondly, read about [`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair).

Comment: By the way, the second `for` loop will access `jeuJoueur2` out of bounds

Comment: Are you sure you want to be passing arrays of string around?

Comment: And also: Why do you want to return 2 arrays here? Your function only ever fills one of them with values

Comment: Need to learn about passing by reference in c++

Comment: @pablo-clsn read about pointers and whats the relation between them and arrays, then you can return as many arrays as you want from a function and no need of structs and vectors for such basic tasks.

Comment: @Amitesh This is C++, so it is better to write idiomatic code

Comment: @stackptr I am well aware about the language but what you are telling is that the person first read all the concepts behind templates and OOP before understanding basic call by reference and pointers would be just too much, answers should also be related to the context of the question.

Comment: You can return a tuple or pair, and grab them from the caller with std::tie, but there are serious issues with your code there.  You've not only accessed your `jeuJoueur2` out of bounds, but the way your function is written, you will always return some sort of uninitialized array.  It looks like you want to parameterize your function better, or split it into two different functions.

Answer (score 2):

You can, if you use `std::array` instead of raw arrays:

```
std::array<std::array<std::string, 26>, 2> couperJeu(int idJoueur, string tab[52]) {
    std::array<std::array<std::string, 26>, 2> jeuJoueur;

    // fill jeuJoueur[0]/jeuJoueur[1] instead of jeuJoueur1/jeuJoueur2

    return jeuJoueur;
}
```

but you shouldn't. You only fill either `jeuJoueur1` or `jeuJoueur2`, never both. Therefore, there is never a reason to return both.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a C++ question, you should use C++ data types, like `std::vector`, which will simplify your code.

```
const int DECKSIZE = 52;
std::pair<std::vector<card>, std::vector<card> > cut(
                int idPlayer, std::vector<card> arr)
{
    std::vector<card> a;
    std::vector<card> b;

    if (idPlayer == 0)
        for (int i = 0; i < DECKSIZE / 2; ++i)
            a.push_back(arr[i]);

    if (idPlayer == 1)
        for (int i = DECKSIZE / 2; i < DECKSIZE; ++i)
            b.push_back(arr[i]);

    return std::make_pair(a, b);
}
```

Notice the use of `DECKSIZE` instead of the magic numbers `52` and `26`. This improves code readability.

But the code you suggest doesn't really make sense--if you are populating one of the arrays, why would you return both?

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. In c++ isn't possible to return two arguments from function.

You can try use for example **std::pair<>** or define a struct to return two arguments

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to pass a **reference** to the function as a parameter, or in C-style code, a pointer.  The function can then modify the object by reference, and the changes will be visible to the caller.  This has the advantages that updating the array in place is much more efficient than making a deep copy, and that you can update as many objects as you want without the function having to manage memory.

On the other hand, returning a temporary `vector` or `string` object (**not** a reference to a temporary, which is illegal) will get optimized to make a more efficient shallow copy.  You could also force this behavior for other kinds of arguments by wrapping them in a smart `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`.  And making your function return information through its return values, and not side-effects, is a more functional style that is easier to debug and analyze.

Answer (score -1):

Another way to do what operation you need to do is to make the two arrays global arrays and then create a void function to do all operations needed. Of course you can use vectors instead of arrays, but i recommend arrays if you are new user of c++.

Comment: Why would you recommend the (arguably) unsafer method for newer users? `std::vector` and `std::array` are more idiomatic modern C++ *and* safer to use

Comment: Yes, but a new c++ user is unfamiliar with vectors in my opinion. Of course, vectors are more powerfull and need no control from the programmer (I agree from this perspective with you).

Comment: New programmers are also unfamiliar with raw arrays and learning how to use `std::vector` or `std::array` takes about the same effort (probably even less because it removes many common causes of mistakes)

Comment: Generally I agree with you sir, but a new user in my opinion has to learn first the "c" way in order to understand better c++ , which is a better c . My opinion always .

Comment: C++ is **not** a *"better"* C - they are two separate languages that share a common ancestry but have evolved differently. There is no need to learn C to write C++ code (in fact a lot of C code doesn't even compile in C++).

Comment: Of course they are different, but knowing C will help someone get better faster with c++.

Comment: @dimkatsi Not necessarily. Knowing C helps some people write poor and/or unidiomatic C++ code, when not knowing C++ would have got them looking for good C++ reference material.